# What can be Short cut Code for following

Tags: vb.net, linq, foreach

Short Code for:

```
    Dim NewItemList As List(Of OrderDetail) = New List(Of OrderDetail)

    For Each Item As OrderDetail In OrderInfoDetails
        If Item.Status = EnumOrderStatus.Taken Then
            NewItemList.Add(Item)
        End If
    Next
```

Tried:

```
    Dim NewItemList As List(Of OrderDetail) = From Item As OrderDetail In OrderInfoDetails Where Item.Status = EnumOrderStatus.Taken Select Item
```

But got a error saying cannot convert where list of orderdetail to generic list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about simply

```
Dim NewItemList = OrderInfoDetails.Where(Function(e) e.Status = EnumOrderStatus.Taken).ToList()
```

For a simple `Where` I prefer the method syntax. You want a `List(Of OrderDetail)` instead of a `IEnumerable(Of OrderDetail)`, so you can just call the `ToList()` extension method.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your query in a List constructor:

```
Dim NewItemList = New List(Of OrderDetail)(From Item As OrderDetail In OrderInfoDetails Where Item.Status = EnumOrderStatus.Taken Select Item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Where(...)` method testing the `Status` property for equivalency to `EnumOrderStatus.Taken` via lambda expression, then call the ToList() method